# RISC-V softcore GPIO (memory mapped) sends the first value and fails later

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, gpio, riscv, memory-mapped-io

I have a RISC-V softcore based SoC ([PICO-SoC](https://github.com/drichmond/RISC-V-On-PYNQ/blob/9eba461cd98ace8bb36caafef2680e1fab8b7b3a/notebooks/tutorial/4-Packaging-An-Overlay.ipynb)) and I have implemented memory (32'h 00000090) mapped output port to send a set of values. The set up is running on PYNQ FPGA board. The softcore provides a web-based interface — Python notebook, to compile and execute application software on RISC-V. When I execute the below application software, I notice only te first value arrives at the output port and then the program exits (probably some exception occurs).

```c
%%riscvc test overlay.tutorialProcessor

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>   

#define reg_outp (*(volatile int*)0x00000090) 

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    unsigned int * arr = (unsigned int *)argv[1];

    reg_outp = 7;           
    reg_outp = 9;            
    reg_outp = 15;

    return arr[2];           
}
```

The first line is used for compiling. Post compiling the code is executed as below

```python
import numpy as np

arg1 = np.array([4,2,3], np.uint32)
retval = overlay.tutorialProcessor.run(test, arg1)
if (retval != arg1[2]):
    print("Test failed!")
else:
    print("Test passed!")
```

The result says `Test failed!` and, in the output port, I see only 7, which is the first value sent (The output port is connected to debug core to see the received values). If I comment the lines which writes to output port, then the software executes as expected with the result `Test passed!`

Below is the snippet for the memory mapped output port implementation.

```verilog
always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (!resetn) begin
            gpio <= 0;
        end else begin
            rmem_ready <= 0;
            if (mem_valid && !mem_ready && mem_addr[31:0] == 32'h 00000090) begin
                rmem_ready <= 1;
                if (mem_wstrb[0]) gpio[ 7: 0] <= mem_wdata[ 7: 0];
                if (mem_wstrb[1]) gpio[15: 8] <= mem_wdata[15: 8];
                if (mem_wstrb[2]) gpio[23:16] <= mem_wdata[23:16];
                if (mem_wstrb[3]) gpio[31:24] <= mem_wdata[31:24];
            end
        end
    end
```

I am not sure why I am not getting the subsequent values after 7 at the output port. Is the program exiting after sending the first value due to some exception? what could be possibly going wrong here? Is the memory (0x00000090) that I mapped corresponds to code area? Where can I find the memory mapping and to which memory area should I connect the output port?

Comment: Linkers are commonly able to generate a cross-reference. Use that to check the memory layout. -- Did you check the resulting assembler/machine code?

Comment: I am novice in this. Can you please elaborate on how I can check the cross reference?

Comment: Start by [edit]ing your question to add the compiler and its version, and optimally how you built the executable (command lines). If it is not a common compiler/linker system, please add also links to its documentation.